# Setting up database dates with ORMs

Tags: php, database, database-design, orm, doctrine-orm

I have been thinking/researching the best way to handle my entity dates in conjunction with an ORM tool.  Currently I am using Doctrine2(php 5.3) with a MySQL driver(if anyone needs to know).

So my situation is as follows:  I have a system that tracks WorkOrders and their Invoices from collaborating subcontractors.  So a WorkOrder may have numerous invoices submitted by same/different subcontractors which will aggregate for a given pay period. This amount, is paid to the subcontractor. My question is what is the best way to handle fetching invoices that fall into a specific pay period/ or any date range for that matter? As an example I have a table which displays the totals for each subcontractor for each week in a year, but I also display totals for a month etc..  In addition I have a calendar view which displays the same invoices aggregated by day and week.

Currently I pass a date range(fromDate/thruDate) along with a class which is configured to iterate the result set and compose collections based on different criteria such as unit of time to aggregate results and a calculator to handle the totaling of the invoices based on user role and/or invoice type.  This way seems to be very flexible so far, however I am concerned with the performance impact of fetching say 10,000 invoices, having doctrine hydrate the objects, me iterating the result set, and then iterating again in my view to display.  I am thinking I could eliminate one step of me iterating the result step by looking into a custom hydrator.

I have also been thinking about setting up a entity with each date from the 'date of origin' of the system to a relevant current/future date with relationships to weeks/months/quarters/years which would save me the hassle of forming my own collections from the result set.  This method seems like it would be nice especially since when I pass a date range to fetch invoices to display on a calendar, I have to find and pass fromDates and thruDate which more often than not extend into previous and future months because of how the weeks are totaled.  I am beginning to lean more toward this approach but I have a feeling when I begin to implement it that I will begin to run into problems.

So enough rambling on for now, I'll just ask.  Can anyone give me any pointers/tips/lessons learned/ reading material/ etc... on this subject.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: tl;dr Sorry, what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea may be to hydrate as an array when displaying the data and only hydrate into objects when you need to work with an individual invoice.

Another approach may be to limit the number of entities returned into a paginated list to ensure you have a known maximum number of objects being returned.

Hope that helps

Comment: I thought about hydrating to array, but the pricing/costing logic is in the different subclasses of invoices. I suppose I could move the logic into another class and just pass in an array, but to be honest I would rather copy the needed logic to the sql and return an already calculated result set.

Comment: You could use static methods from within those classes that returns the results based on the value from the array. Would that work in your case?